# Information about SYN

Tags: networking, tcp

I'm new to socket programming and i read that SYN packet can be created through a raw socket .But windows api doesn't allow the creation of a raw socket .I know that ICMP packet doesn't have any port binding to it and where as TCP SYN has a port binding onto it and they both are raw sockets .Is TCP SYN an ICMP control message in anyway ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. TCP is a component which operates at Layer 4 and provides session control for user data. ICMP is a component which operates at Layer 3 and generally provides control messaging and is not used to transport user data.

I don't meant to sound like a jerk, but it sounds like you need a better understanding of how networks work and of the OSI Model, before progressing to something as advanced as socket programming.

Try the Wikipedia article (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OSI_model) or look for some books or YouTube videos, however you learn best.